# C# creating rectangles to place form elements

Tags: c#, rectangles

i need some help on how to create rectangles as separator in my C# form (i don't want group box).
Thank you.

Comment: `Panel` (with custom painting if you want)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw them?

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    base.OnPaint(e);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red, new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100));
}
```